Random reboots after upgrade from 22.04 to 24.04; perplexing
About 1 month ago I performed an upgrade on my system from 22.04 to 24.04. Previous to this upgrade the system was very stable, no problems. Right after I performed the upgrade the system began intermittently rebooting itself. (i.e. Ubuntu is running and running nothing or effectively nothing and then I am seeing the BIOS screen).
After searching, I found people who said "Do a fresh install". I backed up my /home/user, and /etc and I reinstalled 24.04 freshly.  Upon reinstall, I only took my old samba conf from /etc and I took my user files from /home/user and began again to configure and use my newly installed Ubuntu machine.  To my surprise, it again intermittently rebooted on me. Many times the machine is just sitting there and it reboots.
I have been perplexed by this because it is behaving as if there was a hardware problem, but there was zero hardware change before and after the upgrade.  The machine has good airflow and have no reason to suspect overheating is occurring. Many/most times it is simply idling when it resets.
My attempts to resolve or isolate the problem thus far include (not necessarily in sequence order):

Updating the BIOS to the latest available.  (MB is ASUS ROG STRIX B550-F (wifi))
Full memtest86.  Took 2 hours 28 minutes to fully test 128GB, running SMP.  I figured SMP was good because it would test multiple cores on the processor. No failure.
CPU burn test where loaded my CPU (AMD Ryzen 5 5600X) for a bit. No failure.
Verified the latest graphics drivers for graphics card (AMD Radeon RX 580)
Performed a GPU test using Unigine valley. No failure.
Disabled Wi-Fi and Bluetooth features on the motherboard. Uncontrolled reboot still occurred
Switched power supply with a brand new one. Uncontrolled reboot still occurred.
I enabled kernel debugging logging (I think) by adding: kernel.printk = 7 7 1 7 to /etc/sysctl.conf  and then verified that this was enabled by using cat /proc/sys/kernel/printk

I have not been able to isolate anything consistently happening in the logs. For instance, if I take the output of last reboot and look at the recent ones:
reboot   system boot  6.8.0-48-generic Wed Nov 20 16:01   still running
reboot   system boot  6.8.0-48-generic Wed Nov 20 15:43   still running
reboot   system boot  6.8.0-48-generic Wed Nov 20 15:25 - 15:43  (00:17)
reboot   system boot  6.8.0-48-generic Wed Nov 20 14:49 - 15:43  (00:53)
reboot   system boot  6.8.0-48-generic Wed Nov 20 14:40 - 14:48  (00:08)
reboot   system boot  6.8.0-48-generic Wed Nov 20 13:23 - 14:48  (01:24)
reboot   system boot  6.8.0-48-generic Wed Nov 20 12:19 - 14:48  (02:28)
reboot   system boot  6.8.0-48-generic Wed Nov 20 11:36 - 14:48  (03:12)

Those times represent the system restarted. Normally it says "still running" when it faults and reboots but then there is some kind of cleanup. Almost all of the above represent uncontrolled reboots with the exception of perhaps 2 where I was adjusting configuration and wanted to make sure it was active.
If I go to /var/log/kern.log and I search backwards for "Linux version" (first log of a reboot), I can see the logs that occurred right before the reboot. There doesn't seem to be consistently a same cause.  For instance, here is 16:01.
2024-11-20T15:44:48.904343-07:00 svr kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1732142688.903:192): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" class="cap" profile="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=4428 comm="snap-confine" capability=38  capname="perfmon"
2024-11-20T16:01:55.246557-07:00 svr kernel: Linux version 6.8.0-48-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-010) (x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-13 (Ubuntu 13.2.0-23ubuntu4) 13.2.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.42) #48-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Sep 27 14:04:52 UTC 2024 (Ubuntu 6.8.0-48.48-generic 6.8.12)

and there is 15:43
2024-11-20T15:43:09.543269-07:00 svr kernel:  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=101 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
2024-11-20T15:43:35.769171-07:00 svr kernel: Linux version 6.8.0-48-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-010) (x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-13 (Ubuntu 13.2.0-23ubuntu4) 13.2.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.42) #48-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Sep 27 14:04:52 UTC 2024 (Ubuntu 6.8.0-48.48-generic 6.8.12)

Note first that there is a significant log gap between the logs.  For instance, 16:01 there was a 15 minute gap between the last kernel log and the reboot.  While it was closer to 20 seconds of silence in the 15:43 reboot.  I have seen other reboots where there was binary garbage in the logs prior to the reboot, for instance this one:
2024-11-19T11:00:56.597426-07:00 svr kernel:  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=101 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
^@^@^@[many ^@ snipped]^@2024-11-19T11:03:04.550077-07:00 svr kernel: Linux version 6.8.0-48-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-010) (x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-13 (Ubuntu 13.2.0-23ubuntu4) 13.2.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.42) #48-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Sep 27 14:04:52 UTC 2024 (Ubuntu 6.8.0-48.48-generic 6.8.12)
2024-11-19T11:03:04.550299-07:00 svr kernel: Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-48-generic root=UUID=60c9acc4-90f4-4d74-acdc-ad21be5bbc15 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7

I am at a loss as to what could be happening. This machine has been wonderful and stable for several years on 22.04. And then straight away after I installed 24.04, it started randomly resetting.  In between those random resets, it works great. :(
If someone could tell me "enable this setting" and look at this log and we can find out what the cause of the reset is, I would love that!!!
One piece of confessional data (the stuff that only comes out at the end of long troubleshooting sessions):
My son used to have the mobo/proc in his machine running Windows and I had other hardware in my machine. Something happened and his Windows crashed -- ugly. I could not repair it using regular windows USB means, so I fully zero'ed out his hard drive booting from an Ubuntu USB using dd from /dev/zero to his drive. I tried many times and many ways to reinstall Windows 10, but it would not work even though it was effectively a fresh system.
My ultimate conclusion was that I would take this mobo/proc and switch with the one that I had in my machine. Worked great, until I installed Ubuntu 24.04.
Given the crazy nature of this problem, my best speculation is: Some subtle hardware failure happened on the motherboard in such a place that Windows could not run or install. Ubuntu 22.04 ran and worked just fine because maybe it didn't use that piece of hardware??? And then some change in the kernel/software of Ubuntu 24.04 now uses that hardware and now it is fine? It is strange that I have had such great success on 22.04 for so long.
I have two other sons, one running Windows 10 and one running Ubuntu 24.04 on this exact motherboard and processor combination. No problem.
Since it is not the power supply, maybe something sketchy to a component in the motherboard and I should just have a good cry over it and pony up the $$$ for a new one?
UPDATE
UGH!!  After replacing the motherboard, I am still experiencing uncontrolled reboots!
reboot   system boot  6.8.0-49-generic Fri Nov 22 11:06   still running
reboot   system boot  6.8.0-49-generic Fri Nov 22 03:30   still running
reboot   system boot  6.8.0-49-generic Fri Nov 22 09:21 - 09:27  (00:05)
reboot   system boot  6.8.0-48-generic Wed Nov 20 18:12 - 09:21 (1+15:08)

What gives???   New power supply, new motherboard.  CPU tested, memory tested.
The reboot happened again while the system was effectively idling -- I had walked away.
UPDATE 2
Switching the power strip/surge protector did not make a difference. I am resorting to elimination of anything non-necessary to see if it makes the difference.
I disconnected an HDMI cable connected to a 4K TV that acted as a second monitor. I had plugged into my graphics card a 4K monitor connected via Display Port and a 4K TV connected via HDMI. It has been up for nearly 2 hours since I disconnected that. I am going to leave the machine running over night with simple apps up. If it is still up in the morning, I'll feel foolish but be happy to have it resolved. Would a bad HDMI cable do this?  Is it bad to connect a computer to a 4K TV?
Resolution
The machine stayed up all night without that HDMI cable connected to the TV. Best explanation I can guess is perhaps I subtly jostled and damaged the cable around the same time as the 24.04 upgrade.  Wish I had thought to test this first. @david's suggestion of verifying that it still happens on 22.04 probably would have been a good diagnostic to eliminate analytic assumptions, but I didn't want to spend the effort at the time. I hope everyone can be more wise than me. :)  Thanks to all who invested any energy or interest.

If the cause were software, there would likely be some kind of log entry plainly written in syslog or journal "reboot triggered by...". The lack of useful logs is another clue suggesting some sort of hardware fault.

Good observation.

You might try running memtest86. I think you can do this either from the grub menu or a USB stick.

Did that.  See #2 above.  2 hours 28 minutes.

To see if it is 24.04 causing the problem you could re-install 22.04 and see if the problems persists. The 'last reboot' data shows it was an uncontrolled shutdown, the sort of thing you get when the hardware fails due to undervoltage. (There will be plenty of other things though.) You can get this when you set the unit into suspend-hybrid (its sets up hibernate but goes into suspend so if the voltage drops and the processor fails (low volts) it falls back on hibernate.

It might be worth looking through the BIOS information. A bit of a long shot. Try and run 'sudo dmidecode'  'man dmidecode for details and depending on you BIOS it might, if you are lucky, tell you something.

Thank you David.  I took a look at those things, but I think I am not smart enough to discriminate and identify an error.  I have a new motherboard sitting here, same model + 1 (ROG STRIX B550-F GAMING WIFI II)  the II is the interesting part.  I am going to put it in.  I will post back if for any reason that turns out to not be it -- which would render me totally confused.

Up and running on new mobo.  Will update if anything doesn't work. We can assume hardware problem for now.  Thanks to all who read, considered and commented.

I think maybe I will replace the surge bar that this machine is plugged into.

I’m voting to close this question because it is a hardware issue, specifically related to the HDMI cable.

Yes, thank you.

Resolved.  Some issue with HDMI or more likely the HDMI cable caused a hardware problem that caused the resets.
